Is it possible bake a (2D) mask animation (python magic maybe)?
I started rotoscoping a car. I use a mask shape. Because the car is quite trackable, I parented the mask shape points to a tracker. However the track is not perfect because it goes off-screen. Instead of finding the "perfect" tracker point, I would finish the rotoscoping by hand.
So the question: can I bake the animation from the tracker (via parenting) into the shape points?
Is there a workaround via python?


